# When clicked inside UITextview in ios 8, keyboard not popping but works well in ios 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, xcode6

mu iOS application run on `Xcode 6.0`  and when clicked inside `UITextfield` then not popping `UIKeyboard`. please give me solution about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this problem happening in the Simulator only? Try going to Hardware->Keyboard->Toggle Software Keyboard, or hit command-K.

Comment: thank you but still i did not find Hardware option in Xcode 6 Simulator? can you tell me again step in deep?

Comment: The Hardware menu is located on the app's menu bar on the top of the screen.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark this answer as correct so others will know where to look, and so I can collect the reputation points :)

Answer (score 1):

sometimes it happening ,select your simulator and go to the menu,  just remove the `check mark` in `connect Hardware Keyboard`

[image]

Comment: have a happy day my brother , if my answer is useful give the up vote